# Copy/pasting cells with shapes

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

How can copy a shape along with the cell it is in? When I copy manually the shape follows the cell, but when I do it with a macro I get everything else but the shape.

```
Cells(sourceRow, sourceColumn).Copy
Cells(targetRow, targedColumn).PasteSpecial
```

...

```
Range("A1").copy
Range("B2").PasteSpecial Operation:=xlPasteAll
```

I've tried all I could think of... but the shape just won't move.

Recorded the manual copy/paste and this is what I got:

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: you may perform the copy manually while recording the macro.

Comment: I just did, but didn't help much. I have pasted the recorded macro in the question.

Comment: The recorded code should paste the shape into cell `A3`. Is this not the case?

Comment: It should, but do I have to select the cell? Can't I paste it directly to a cells() or a range()?

Comment: Yes, you got to select the cell as Range/Cell did not have that "Paste" function supported

Comment: It did work, I'm fiddling with this to see if i can avoid having to select a cell. (In a loop it will slow the program down.)

Comment: So this is the only way to do this? Can't I avoid selecting?

Comment: Well that certainly works. I was trying to do it without selecting cells as that will make my loops run slower. But if is not possible to get around that, then I'll use this solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @jony See my answer as a possible option for avoiding the use of `select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this to avoid having to actually select the cell:

```
Sub MoveShape()

  Dim s As Shape
  Dim T, L, celWidth, shpWidth, celHeight, shpHeight As Double
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim ws as Worksheet

  Set s = ws.Shapes(1).Duplicate ''You'll have to get the index of the shape you want to copy 
  Set rng = Range("A3") ''Set this to your target range

  T = rng.Top
  L = rng.Left

  celWidth = rng.Width
  shpWidth = s.Width

  celHeight = rng.Height
  shpHeight = s.Height

  s.Top = T + (celHeight - shpHeight) / 2
  s.Left = L + (celWidth - shpWidth) / 2

End Sub
```

This will duplicate your shape, and put the resulting clone in the centre of your target range. You can change its position in the cell by modifying the `s.Left` and `s.Top` values.

You can now use `Range("A3").Value = Range("A1").Value` to copy the actual values of the cell to your target range

Comment: Your solution seems great. That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
[image: before]

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

[image: After]

Comment: Yes that works. I was trying to do it without selecting cells as that will make my loops run slower. But if is not possible to get around that, then I'll take what I can get. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can put `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to enhance your script performance